# Python Shapely - Checking if line contains a point

Tags: python, numpy, intersection, shapely

I am having troubles checking if a `LineString` contains the `Point` resulting from an intersection with a `Polygon` using the Shapely library.

Example code:

```
l = LineString([(5.653154885795476, 6.418676641285647), (6.132921674075812, 5.995573963137367)])
o = LineString([(5, 7.5), (6, 6)])
p = l.intersection(o)
# --> p = Point(5.817513045918756, 6.273730431121867)
```

But when running `l.intersects(p)` or `l.contains(p)` or `l.touches(p)` I always get `False`, which doesn't make much sense since `p` is the result of an intersection.

I read about floating point imprecisions, adding the following snippet before checking as above:

```
ll = list(line.coords)
for i, v in enumerate(ll):
  ll[i] = Point(np.round(np.array(v), 4))
l = LineString(ll)
p = Point(np.round(np.array(p), 4))
```

but to no avail.

I need this to check which part of a `LineString` intersects the point; is this wrong? Are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it is a floating point precision issue. You can use this workaround:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString

l = LineString([(5.653154885795476, 6.418676641285647), (6.132921674075812, 5.995573963137367)])
o = LineString([(5, 7.5), (6, 6)])
p = l.intersection(o)

print(l.distance(p)<1e-8)
print(o.distance(p)<1e-8)
```

Output:

```
True
True
```